# Is there any way to know LSODE internal time steps?

Tags: timestamp, octave, differential-equations

I am trying to solve non-linear differential equations using LSODE. I want to know that is there any way to know that how much time steps lsode takes internally? and is there any way to restrict lsode for certain time steps?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use lsode_options to fine-tune lsode.

The default options are

```
Options for LSODE include:

keyword                                             value
-------                                             -----
absolute tolerance                                  1.49012e-08
relative tolerance                                  1.49012e-08
integration method                                  stiff
initial step size                                   -1
maximum order                                       -1
maximum step size                                   -1
minimum step size                                   0
step limit                                          100000
```